# How do I get my bounty points back?

Tags: support

I recently posted a question that our team was unable to resolve and assigned 100 points as a "bounty". Unfortunately no one was able to answer that question and we only got one comment that was of no help.

The bounty period has expired but I didn't get the points back.

From further research and posting elsewhere we found no solution but we did find a workaround, so we answered our own question.

How can I get my points back?

Comment: You don't get your points back once a bounty is offered

Comment: You can get 100 points back in like an hour. Just answer a few easy questions, get a couple upvotes and an accept or two and they'll be back :) also, this post belongs on meta

Comment: Really. I think that if the experts here cannot answer the question, then I should get the point back x 5 times. But don't get me wrong. We did and still do need a solution for our problem. So it's most disappaointing all round.

Answer (score 6):

From the [bounty privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties):

> The reputation you're using for the bounty is immediately and irreversibly deducted from your reputation.